# Alinhar colunas de uma tabela html de maneira independente, por exemplo, as duas primeiras alinhadas à esquerda e as demais à direita

Tags: css, html5

Tenho este código simples e quero alinhar as duas primeiras colunas à esquerda e as demais à direita. Só consigo alinhar todas e não de modo independente.

```
  thead, th {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aquamarine;
  }

  thead, tr td {
  font-size: 18;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: rgb(229, 228, 208);
  }
</style>

<title>Tabela de clientes</title>
```

#### Clientes

Nome do cliente
      Endereço
      Idade
      Valor a débito R$
      Valor a crédito R$
   
    
  
  
    
      Marcos
      Rua Pajé, 76
      58
      345.98
      254.77

```
<tr>
  <td>João</td>
  <td>Rua das Orquídeas, 546</td>
  <td>36</td>
  <td>112.12</td>
  <td>223.09</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Luiz</td>
  <td>Rua dos Cogumelos, 231</td>
  <td>65</td>
  <td>8.89</td>
  <td>12.45</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue afetar cada coluna individualmente com base na posição das `<td>` dentro de cada linha. Eu faria algo assim:

```css
td {
   text-align: right;
}

td:first-child, td:nth-child(2) {
   text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito.  Era a resposta que eu precisava. Eu havia tentado de várias maneiras, mas não tinha conseguido.  Muito obrigado!